# PHP OOP - Sending simple message and insert it to database

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a PHP script for myself which gets data from a form and simply send it to a database. It looks like this:

```
 class Users {
  /* Deklarovanie premennych */
     public $name = null;
     public $email = null;
     public $phone = null;
     public $message = null;

     public function __construct( $array = array() ) {
         if( isset( $data['name'] ) ) $this->name = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['name'] ) );
         if( isset( $data['email'] ) ) $this->email = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['email'] ) );
         if( isset( $data['phone'] ) ) $this->phone = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['phone'] ) );
         if( isset( $data['message'] ) ) $this->message = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['message'] ) );
     /* využitá funkcia stripslashes pre odstránenie "\" ktoré mohol vložiť užívateľ do formulara */
     }

     public function storeFormValues( $formvalues ) {
        $this->__construct( $formvalues );
    /*uložíme hodnoty zíaskne z $_POST*/ 
     }

     public function message() {
        $correct = false;
            try {
                $db_con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
                $db_con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
                $sql = "INSERT INTO user(name, email, phone, message) VALUES(:name, :email, :phone, :message)";

                $stmt = $db_con->prepare( $sql );
                $stmt->bindValue( "name", $this->name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $stmt->bindValue( "email", $this->email, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $stmt->bindValue( "phone", $this->phone, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $stmt->bindValue( "message", $this->message, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $stmt->execute();
                return "Správa bola úspešne odoslaná!! <br/> <a href='index.php'>pozrieť správy!</a>";
            }catch( PDOException $exce ) {
                return $exce->getMessage();
            }
     }

 }

?>
```

In my eyes the code looks fine and understandable. It doesn't throw any errors but the problem is that it doesn't insert anything into the database. I am not sure where the problem can be.

And I nearly forgot this is my index part:

```
<?php 
} else {
    $Users = new Users;
    $Users->storeFormValues( $_POST );
    if( $Users->message() ) {
        echo "Sprava bola úspešne odoslana";    
    } else {
        echo "Sprava nebola odoslana";    
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Try adding colon before each reference variables names, $stmt->bindValue( ":name", $this->name, PDO::PARAM_STR ); //Also for email, phone, message

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate but it didnt change anything :(

Comment: @SyedQarib - They aren't required at all (though people seems to love the burden of adding them ;-)

Comment: Thanks @ÁlvaroG.Vicario for adding that to my knowledge :)

Comment: Side note: do you really know what `stripslashes( strip_tags() )` does? You're destroying user data! You could as well insert random text in it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Im one of those people ;p a glutton for punishment

Comment: When you `return $e->getMessage()` from these methods on failure, that is a string value. If you check `if ($Users->message())` but that `message()` method returns the error string, the `if()` condition is _positive_.  Don't confuse the return values from your methods. If it is in an error state, throw the exception higher or something else. Don't return the error as a string.

Comment: Note, your 'bind param' name  MUST include the colon as the prefix to the parameter name. i.e. use : '$stmt->bindValue(":name", $this->name, PDO::PARAM_STR );' note the colon (':') as a prefix to the parameter ''name'. You are missing the leading 'colons'

Comment: I do not why you use the function 'stripslashes' - unless are certain that the 'addslashes' function was used elsewhere. I would not bother until notified that i had to use it.